# Why can't I see the Cycles Rendering button in Node Editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

When I enter into the Node Editor to mess around with materials, i'm greeted with no cycles render button, nor any of the others.[image]

The buttons aren't there.

Please help, I've tried to see if it was enabled in Add-ons and it was, yet it's just not there in the node editor. I've also tried to change my rendering from CPU to GPU rendering, but to no avail, it's not there.

Please assist me, I've had this problem ever since i got blender.

Comment: "*I've had this problem ever since i got blender.*" That is expected, render buttons were never in the Node Editor header.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: have you switched from Blender Render to Cycles Render in the top horizontal menu bar?

Answer (score 1):

There is no cycles render button on the node editor.

To switch render engines the button is in the **info** window.

[image]

then select your render engine

[image]

If that is not the button you are looking for please add an image on the original question that shows what buttons you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

Cycles workflow is not like Blender Render (which is what i assume you've been using so far). Just follow the steps below and you'll be good to go.

1. The yellow box is the "Outliner" panel. Select the object here.
2. The green box is in the "Materials" tab of the "Properties Editor". Click the "+" button on the right side of the green box to add a material to your object.
3. Check "Use Nodes" in the cyan box.
4. The green box is in the "Render" tab of the "Properties Editor". You can select your render device (CPU or GPU) there.
5. The magenta box is the workspace of the node editor. Make sure you have shaders (BSDFs) connected to an "Material Output" node or you won't see anything in the render (or just black objects).
6. Press the render button in the red box (again in the "Render" tab of the "Properties Editor") once you've set up materials for all visible objects in your scene, and you're good to go.

I hope this helps.

[image: Cycles workflow]

You also sometimes need to press the button in the red box and select the material for the active (selected) object from the drop-down list as seen below.

[image]

Comment: That didn't work, those 4 buttons next the material list in the Node Editor is what i'm looking for, it doesn't seem to show up for me

Comment: I updated my answer, the additional step should fix your problem.